# Java throws a java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dir/file.xlsx "Permission denied"

Tags: java, excel, unix, apache-poi, file-permissions

I'm using POI API to read a XLSX file, that I want to convert it to a CSV file. The xlsx file is dropped in a server, the file permissions are -rw-r--r--.

This is the code I'm using:

```
    public void processFirstSheet(String filename) throws Exception {

    OPCPackage pkg = null;
    try{
        FileUtil.set777Permissions(filename);
        pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename,PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
    }catch(Exception e){
        log.warning("OPCPackage: "+ e.getMessage());
    }

    try{
        XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg );
        SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();

        // creating the needed parser instance which will
        // generate the needed rows
        XMLReader parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(ORG_APACHE_XERCES_PARSERS_SAX_PARSER);
        ContentHandler handler = new RowGenerator(sst);
        parser.setContentHandler(handler);

        Iterator<InputStream> sheets = r.getSheetsData();
        // if there are no sheets to open, return
        if(!sheets.hasNext())
            return;
        // for the moment we parse the first sheet
        InputStream sheet = sheets.next();
        try {
            InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet);
            parser.parse(sheetSource);
        } finally {
            sheet.close();
        }
    } finally {
        if(pkg!=null)
            pkg.close();
    }
}
```

When debugging, the pkg.close() throws an exception as following:

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dir/file.xlsx (Permission denied)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.FileHelper.copyFile(FileHelper.java:68)
            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.closeImpl(ZipPackage.java:334)
            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.close(OPCPackage.java:417)
            at project.format.readers.impl.GCSXlsxReader.processFirstSheet(XlsxReader.java:96)
            at project.format.readers.impl.XlsxReader.<init>(XlsxReader.java:54)
            at project.format.impl.FileConverter.readAndConvert(FileConverter.java:135)
            at project.format.impl.FileConverter.convert(FileConverter.java:66)
            at project.watcher.impl.GCSDirectoryWatcher.startWatchinginDirectory(DirectoryWatcher.java:66)
            at project.watcher.impl.GCSDirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:31)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Dec 15, 2013 2:12:24 PM project.watcher.impl.FeedHelper archiveFile
```

What I can see, I cannot set permissions 777 to the file. The user running the application is a specific user created for this application running on a Unix server.

But when connected via SSH to the server, I can set chmod 777 to the the file. It looks like it's a user issue, but don't know how to overcome it.

Any advices?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you please add output of ls -ld /dir/ and ls -l /dir/file.xlsx , can you also add info which user is used to run the java code, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trying to save a copy of the file - I'm guessing it's trying to save some changes that have been made to the file. In order to do this the file would need to have write permissions set on it for the application user, or the owner would need to be changed.

Comment: Yep, indeed... That was more likely related to the permissions on the file... Thanks for your help!